# MySQL5.6 stuck on the process " attempting to start service "

Tags: mysql

I got a community server version of MySQL5.6 for windows7 32 bit.
and also downloaded windows installer for the same windows version.

Everything was prepared correctly.
I saw on a blog giving me a step-by-step manual for installing MySQL 5.6 on winodws7 32bit.
I did the instruction accordingly and it always stops processing in the phrase of starting service. I completely don't know what the problem is.

I googled it for like three hours and got nothing relevant to this problem.

[image]

It never processes any further without any kind of alerts, no matter how much I wait.

Please help me out.

My OS
Windows7 Ultimate K 32bit, Service Pack1

Comment: This is how I resolved that issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26970454/mysql-configuration-stops-at-starting-server/28400926#28400926

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TURN OFF WINDOWS FIREWALL COMPLETELY BEFORE INSTALLING**

---

This was one of the only threads I could find on this issue and the current answers did not cut the mustard for me.

MySQL 5.6.21, both x86 and x64, did not want to get past "Starting Server" and would give me the "MySQL install taking longer than expected" message.

I tried all of the registry cleaner, folder deletions, etc to no avail.

I am running Windows 7 x64 and I finally decided to check the event viewer to find this:

[image]

0x80070422 turns out to be some unspecified firewall error and boom, it struck me like lightning.

I hope this post helps future visitors!

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed other version of MySQL before？ I have experienced this case ,but I installed MySQL5.5 and uninstalled it. I solved it by clearing regedit and deleting the folder of MySQL in the directory（C:\ProgramData.This directory is hidden by default in Windows.）,then reinstalled it.

Comment: I summarized some possible reasons on my blog [http://www.chenxiusheng.cn/archives/26](http://www.chenxiusheng.cn/archives/26)

Answer (score -1):

Follow this link http://tadeparti.com/pages/?page_id=808.
And do remember to delete everything under the C:\program files\mysql folder, including the odbc stuff if you have.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.