# MySQL Installer Stuck on "Starting Service"

Tags: mysql, installation

I recently had a successful install of MySQL 5.6.21 using the MySQL installer on Windows Server 2012 R2. I needed to make some modifications and tried to re-install.

**Now MySQL is hanging on "Starting Service".**

[image]

**I've tried the following:**

- Uninstall using Control Panel
- Delete Service using "sc delete MySQL56"
- Delete all MySQL files from "Program Files" & "c:\programdata"

Has anyone seen this problem? If so, how were you able to fix it?

Comment: After some reading on that problem I found that people ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19508151/mysql5-6-stuck-on-the-process-attempting-to-start-service) and [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=48871)) seems to have success reinstalling MySQL by cleaning the registry.  You tried that?

Comment: That's exactly what I had to do. I downloaded a registry cleaner, cleared registry, reinstalled and it worked. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26970454/mysql-configuration-stops-at-starting-server) The answer presented in the question which I linked has the best/most correct resolution on what the issue is and how to fix it consistenly. I followed Nenad's answer and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 7):

**TURN OFF WINDOWS FIREWALL COMPLETELY BEFORE INSTALLING**

---

This was one of the only threads I could find on this issue and the current answers did not cut the mustard for me.

MySQL 5.6.21, both x86 and x64, did not want to get past "Starting Server" and would give me the "MySQL install taking longer than expected" message.

I tried all of the registry cleaner, folder deletions, etc to no avail.

I am running Windows 7 x64 and I finally decided to check the event viewer to find this:

[image]

0x80070422 turns out to be some unspecified firewall error and boom, it struck me like lightning.

I hope this post helps future visitors!

Answer (score 7):

I just had that very same problem on Windows 7 pro 64 bit with latest mysql-installer-web-community-5.6.23.0.msi installer and I resolved it [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29243268/1159404) way

Installer stuck because user who is supposed to start service is set erroneously.

Comment: Worked for me in Windows 10. Same issue is there for MySql 5.7 installer too

Comment: Only step 12 (and 13) needed to fix this for mySql80 on Windows Server 2019

Answer (score 3):

I was blooding trying to install MySQL Community Server 5.5.43 on a Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise. On Configuration Screen, the process stops at the "Starting Server." phase.

Okay, first i tried to configure from the installer i downloaded, right after i installed the MySQL. No success at all.

If you already did installed it, please go and unninstall it right from your downloaded file. It both Install and removes the files. Then go to the C:/Program Files/ and delete the MySQL folder. Next, go to Control Panel, Programs, Unninstall and remove the MySQL Community Installer. Rebbot your machine.

Reinstall the software with your downloaded file, but DO NOT PROCEED TO CONFIGURATION! Close the installer when the installation process finishes.

Now, go to C:/program files/MySQL/ MySQL Server 5.5/bin and run (as Administrator) the MySQLInstanceConfig.exe. This file represent the configuration that was supposed to be done by the installer. Folow the procedures and your MySQL Server shoud now recognize that your service has started, passing the "Start Service" phase.

Dolphin Magic!

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem. Didn't work on the server, worked on our personal workstation. As it turns out, I had an environment variable set as follows:

```
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
```

On Windows 7 Enterprise, this is also set but the directory does not exist. So we killed the installer, went to the config file `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini` and changed the setting of `datadir` to a path that existed.

Restart the installer (`MySQLInstanceConfig.exe`, run as administrator) and "reconfigure" your service. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

I have same program

Event viewer detail:

> Plugin keyring_file reported: 'keyring_file initialization failure. Please check if the keyring_file_data points to readable keyring file or keyring file can be created in the specified location. The keyring_file will stay unusable until correct path to the keyring file gets provided'For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://www.mysql.com.

My resolved is:

I Installed data Path and mysql Base Dir on **same disk**

***example***

**(This is working)**

```
 Install Directory : D:\MYSQL
 Data Director :     D:\myData
```

**(This is not working because different disk)**

```
 Install Directory : C:\MYSQL
 Data Director :     D:\myData
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the similar issue during Mysql Upgrade from version 5.7 to 8 .

I have tried by stopping the service (Go to run ->services.msc-> look for Msql5.7) and manually staring Msql8 .After that all the sequential steps where completed and my configuration was completed .

Followed by changing the environment variable Path to your latest Mysql bin path.

There you are , good to go and use your MySQL :)