# Configuration of MySQL server is Taking longer than expected

Tags: mysql

I am trying to install MySQL Server 5.7.17 on my windows 8 computer, while configuring MySQL Server I received following message "Configuration of MySQL Server 5.7.17 is taking longer than expected. for reference here is screenshot of it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ys2gj.png)

However, I searched on internet for the same and I found following answer.

[mysql configuration stops at "starting server"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26970454/mysql-configuration-stops-at-starting-server/29243268#29243268)

Further, while following the instructions and doing same I am getting this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlWnB.png)

Please, Help

Comment: I have the same problem that is described above but for MySQL Server 8.0.29 on my windows 11 computer (OS Build: 22000.675).  I have identical symptoms. I tried to follow the tips @samit, but it doesn't work. After the change that samit describes, I still get the message "... service ...  started and then stopped. ..." Please help.

Comment: The method described by @samit tiwary worked, but with MySQL version 8.0.26.

Answer (score 6):

- **Step 1:** Meanwhile go to Start -> Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services -> find MySQL56, right click on it -> Properties -> select Log On Tab AND HERE IS BUG -> Although Local System Account was selected, Somehow "This account: Network Service (with some password) was selected -> Select Log on as: Local System Account, Allow service to interact with desktop -> Apply -> Go back on general tab
- **Step 2:** On general tab click on "Start" button to start service and here it is! Service is started! Click on OK to close MySQL56 Properties dialog. Close Services dialog. Close Administrative tools. Close control panel.
- **Step 3:** And by that time (while you were closing those dialogs) when you look at MySQl Installer Dialog all steps are finished and checked: Starting Server, Applying security... Creating user accounts.. Updating Start menu link
- **Step 4:**  Confirm with Finish -> Next -> Finish
  That's it, happy MySQL-ing

Posted by Nenad Bulatovic

URL:-https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76476