# Install MySQL but cannot start the server when going into Apply Configuration

Tags: mysql, installation

Having tried to uninstall and clear out files a few times and restart the installation, I still cannot start connecting the server. Any idea on how to fix it? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhiKI.png)

Comment: Could this be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26970454/mysql-configuration-stops-at-starting-server

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm trying to install it again using the tips mentioned in the link. Hope I can get it right.