# Mysql 8.0.29 installation failed

Tags: mysql

The installation failed at this point

[image: The installation failed at this point]

I have already installed Microsoft Visual Studio c++ 2019.

I already uninstalled and delete all the hidden folders.

I read that for someone the solution was to turn off Windows firewall, I already tried it.

I also checked multiple videos of how to install MySQL, but they have the same steps, just a different voice.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try removing the MySQL Package in the Home Menu of your MySQL Installer Community and restart your PC before re-installing it again.

Comment: Have you checked this [mysql configuration stops at "starting server"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26970454/mysql-configuration-stops-at-starting-server)?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check some log information.
2. When you uninstall mysql, you should delete the relevant information about mysql in the registry.

3.install .net 4.5.2+